# Froyo Proxy settings

Tags: 2.2-froyo, proxy

How do I set (global) proxy settings in Froyo? I want to access market, but my college wifi does not work without proxy.

EDIT:
Is there any way to set proxy without rooting?

Answer (score 2):

Wifi proxy settings were not added until Android 3.0 ([here's the issue on the tracker](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1273) and [here is the comment noting its release](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1273#c1647)). If you're willing to root your device you could try something like [TransProxy](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=766569), though.

Comment: Any thing other than rooting? I tried connectify but even connectify has no proxy settings :(  I am feeling unlucky

Comment: @LifeH2O: I don't know of any method that doesn't require rooting if Connectifiy doesn't support it (other than buying your own wireless access point, which I know most colleges in the US would frown upon, don't know about elsewhere).